# Contents of an Interface

Tags: java, interface

What are all the things that an interface can have, apart from abstract method and static variables?

Please give me few explainations. Inputs are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can contain an inner class or interface also. Hava a look at [Map.Entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is your friend:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_interface

The article explains it well and also has examples.

Answer (score 0):

An interface can have inner classes in addition to what you have mentioned.